# Geocoding - get lat/long from 11000 address

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api, address

What I have:

- an Excel file with 11 thousand address (street + zip code + city)
- all address are from Portugal
- the address are not accurate (some address have the name street in a short way)

What I am looking for:

- get "geocodes" (latitude/longitude) of all address.
- using a opensource API, or a service of a website

What I will do with the data collected:

- with the "geocodes" I will create a file like a KML file with all address and some others information about each address
- the "geocodes" will be use in a commercial product by the company I am working.

In my research I have found some API and websites. But I am not sure if they suit my requirements

- Google Maps API

  - I think it was a limit if 2500  requests per IP per day.
  - I think I can not collect the latitude/longitude, only show the location in a Google Map webpage
- Yahoo PlaceFinder API

  - I think it is not free
- website Gisgraphy

  - The results on my test are not good for Portugal address
- website GPS Visualizer's Address Locator

  - uses Google and API Yahoo API, So have the same restrictions above

Some links I found:

- http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/#comment-189818
- https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat?hl=pt-PT#quota-limits

Comment: What is your question - how do you geocode 11,000 addresses for free for commercial use?

Comment: For Europe ViaMichelin is very good and stable for geocoding http://dev.viamichelin.com/web/api-rest/documentation/1.0/geocoding for free see Mapquest Open API http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service

Comment: Yahoo Geocoding (Boss) Placefinder is $4 for 1000 geocodes http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/ [PlaceFinder=10,001 - 35,000  $4.00] so $44 in total.

Comment: @mapperz thnaks for pointing to the free Mapquest Open API, looks very useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [What reliable GeoCoding service would you recommend me?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/what-reliable-geocoding-service-would-you-recommend-me)

Comment: Mapperz, Yes my question is: how to collect all the 11000 geocodes (latitude/longitude) .

Answer (score 6):

I think you will find numerous answers to similar questions on our site by searching the [`geocode`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocoding?sort=votes&pagesize=50) tag.

A few that stick out are:

- [Geocoding API Comparison](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/geocoding-api-comparison)
- [Bulk Geocode 20 million records](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21382/bulk-geocode-20-million-records)
- [What reliable GeoCoding service would you recommend me?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/what-reliable-geocoding-service-would-you-recommend-me)
- [Is there an open source Geocoding tool which can be used commercially?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/is-there-an-open-source-geocoding-tool-which-can-be-used-commercially)
- [Geocoding that's anonymous, good, and free - does it exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6/geocoding-thats-anonymous-good-and-free-does-it-exist)

Comment: Good job with the recursive answer!  Thanks for including some specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will also work for you: [How to find coordinates for a lot of locations based on the town or village name?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44635/how-to-find-coordinates-for-a-lot-of-locations-based-on-the-town-or-village-name)

The presented programme uses Nominatim (Open Street Map). I expect it to also work well with street names in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Openstreetmap (OSM) API can help finding lat,lon information without any subscription/ API key requirement. I have also added a related answer in [How to Geocode a Google SpreadSheet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102839/how-to-geocode-a-google-spreadsheet)

When the address is not accurate, it might bring unexpected results. You might need to get all search results to validate.

1. B1 = Address e.g 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC 20500
2. Replace space with "%20" in address

   B2 `=substitute(B1," ","%20")`
3. Create search link with response in xml format:

   B3 `="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="&B2&"&format=xml&addressdetails=1"`
4. Get lat and lon data in XML format and parse it with XPath filters.

   B4 `=ImportXML(B3,"//place[1]/@lat")`
   B5 `=ImportXML(B3,"//place[1]/@lon")`
5. Get all search results in rows B7
   `=TRANSPOSE(ImportXML(B3,"*"))`

Implementation Example:
[How to find Latitude, Longitude of given address?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p1zvJV35yDQr4Ivs6j-M7HusU6oRojRzFpAYmai3MQU/edit?usp=sharing#gid=391393138)