# Sheetsee optionsJSON problem

Tags: javascript, geojson, maps, visualisation, spreadsheet

I am doing some basic work with G Sheets and Sheetsee.js library.

I have it working as far as I get my coordinates showing up on a map. I'm using the demo-map file as my starter, I just changed the URL key and added my own column names to optionsJSON function.

My problem is, none of my column data is being called into the pop up template. I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code for the script part:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gData
    var URL = "XXXX_MY-KEY-ID-HERE_XXXX" 
    Tabletop.init( { key: URL, callback: showInfo, simpleSheet: true } )
  })

  function showInfo(data) {
    gData = data
    var optionsJSON = ["name", "message", "image"]
    var template = "<ul><li><a href='{{image}}' target='_blank'>"
                 + "<img src='{{image}}'></a></li>"
                 + "<li>Comment: {{message}}</li>"
                 + "<li><h4>Journey: {{name}}</h4></li></ul>"
    var geoJSON = Sheetsee.createGeoJSON(data, optionsJSON)
    var map = Sheetsee.loadMap("map")
    Sheetsee.addTileLayer(map, 'jllord.n7aml2bc')
    Sheetsee.addMarkerLayer(geoJSON, map, template)
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question but it might help for other novice users like myself if I note down the error I was making.

My mistake was that I did not call my coordinates columns 'Lat' and 'Long', but rather was using 'Lat' and 'Lng'. This was because I'm using a script to pull coordinates from location info (sourced via another answer at [How to Geocode a Google SpreadSheet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102839/how-to-geocode-a-google-spreadsheet)). Once I'd realised this and changed column names, everything worked just dandy.